# What's the equivalent of Swift's fatalError() in Kotlin

Tags: swift, kotlin

Say I want to do sth like

```
val foo = when(bar) {
   "one" -> true
   "two" -> false
   else -> // in Swift it would be `fatalError()`
}
```

How do I do it?

I'm aware that there are generally better approaches to this kind of problem, but I want to know how to easily induce a crash in Kotlin too :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could throw an exception. This will bubble up the call stack until somebody handles it or you run out of stack frames and the application crashes.

```
val foo = when(bar) {
   "one" -> true
   "two" -> false
   else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("$bar is Unknown")
}
```

I just used `IllegalArgumentException` here, but you might want to define your own.

Comment: @Sulthan `assert` should only be used for debugging purposes, to catch programming errors, and is not included in the release.

Answer (score 2):

Throwing an exception (or, better still, an [Error](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)) is one way, but it may not shut down the current thread: any of the calling functions could catch the exception, or an [UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) could have been set for the [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) (or its [ThreadGroup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html)).

Nor will it shut down any other threads that may be running.  (Even if you haven't started any yourself, they're used by coroutines, GUI toolkits, and other execution frameworks.)

To shut down the whole app, you should use the Kotlin [`exitProcess()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.system/exit-process.html) function, or in Kotlin/JVM the equivalent [`System.exit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) method.  That will terminate all threads.

But even that will do a ‘graceful’ shutdown, running any shutdown hooks, finalizers, &c.  If you need to forcibly kill a Kotlin/JVM app *immediately*, call [`Runtime.getRuntime().halt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#halt(int)).

(And of course, it's probably good practice to first display something to stdout or the logging framework you're using, to indicate what the problem was.)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the `TODO()` global function in Kotlin:

```kotlin
public inline fun TODO(): Nothing = throw NotImplementedError()
```

You can see that it is a function that returns `Nothing` (similar to Swift's`Never`), and it `throw`s a `NotImplementedError`.

With this, we can create our own `fatalError` function to mimic Swift:

```kotlin
public fun fatalError(message: String = ""): Nothing = throw NotImplementedError(message)
```

And because it returns `Nothing` you can use it the same way you would in Swift:

```kotlin
fun getValue(): Boolean = when(this) {
  "true" -> true
  "false" -> false
  else -> fatalError("Cannot determine value for $this")
}
```

Comment: While this is still technically correct, since implementing this myself it poses an issue with crash reporting since all crashes that hit the fatalError show as the same crash in Firebase etc, making it hard to keep track of individual issues.

Comment: You can solve that with `inline fun` – add `@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")` to make the compiler happy.

Answer (score 0):

Well first, yes I know I'm almost 2 years late but I saw no one said this so I'm going to put this here anyways. What I've done until searching this up is just throw in a TODO.
just like this:
else -> TODO()